# search for form elements in HttpWebresponse-C#

Tags: c#

I have a HTTPPPot whose return I capture using :

```
WebResponse webResponse = httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

Stream responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();

StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

string responseString = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
```

In the response string, the client returns the following

```
<input type="hidden" name="Location" value="sometext.txt"><input type="hidden" name="tableid" value="2"><input type="hidden" name="GroupID" value="1236781329">
```

Based on the above, I need to obtain the values of each form element. I do know the names of the hidden form elements. Is there a quick way to obatin this without reading the entire response line by line and determining if the line contains any pattern that I am lookinng for?

Answer (score 1):

I would use System.Xml.Linq and parse the response into an XElement, and use LINQ to retrieve enumerated lists of nodes and attributes. LinqPad (http://www.linqpad.net/) is a great tool to fine-tune your LINQ queries before you paste it into your code.

Answer (score 0):

You could either do a Regex pattern on the entire string or use [HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack)