# regular expression to locate form elements - c#

Tags: c#

I posted this question yesterday:

[yesterday's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428586/search-for-form-elements-in-httpwebresponse-c)

One of the response was to use Reg Expression to locate the form elements. The clients system, returns a HTML page, and the page contains the following hidden elements -

```
<input type="hidden" name="Location" value="sometext.txt"><input type="hidden" name="tableid" value="2"><input type="hidden" name="GroupID" value="1236781329">
```

How would I use reg exp to locate the elements named Location, tableid, GroupID and its corresponding values.

Is there a online rge expression builder?

Comment: I would substring it and move on with my life!

Comment: i would too, but i wanted to see if there was a better way.. spent way too much time on useless stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than a regular expression, I suggest you use the [HTML agility pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) and use XML-like DOM to access the page structure. It's far more reliable than using regular expressions for something like this.

Comment: Thorain, I did use the HTML agility pack and ran the sample Html2XML and that did not result in what I was looking for. The response from client is not a well formatted HTML.

Comment: The HTML agility pack should be able to handle non well-formed HTML, unless it's really broken. However, it's likely to render properly in all the common browsers then.

Comment: Thorarin: ran through with HTML agility pack. saved the xml it generated when I used HTML2XML test project and loaded the document and tried to find element with "GetElementByTagNAme("utableid")" and that gave me no result. is there a flag that I should use to create the xml with the agility pack?

Comment: Thorarin: The agility pack worked. I was not looking for an attribute and once i noticed by stupidity things seem to work. many thanks

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
foreach(Match m in new Regex("<input(.+)name=\"(?<name>.+)\">").Matches())
    string name = m.Groups["name"].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

A decent online regex tester is [here](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx).