# HttpWebResponse -> How Find A Link With Specific id and class and title?

Tags: c#, .net, element, httpwebresponse, windows

How do I parse HTML to find an anchor (`<a />`) element with specific `id` or `class` or `title`?

Ultimately, I want to find the value of the `href` attribute.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to parse html in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c)

Comment: i know there is a duplicate thread(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428586/search-for-form-elements-in-httpwebresponse-c). but those answers were not enough for me...

Comment: What was the issue with the Agility Pack?

Comment: would you please learn me by an example(answering my Q)? there is no codes in the other thread's answers!

Comment: Every single line that you posted was irrelevant. Hope you don't mind my edit, which just gets to the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(somehtmlstring);

string value = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("a")
    .First(n => n.Attributes["class"].Value == "someclass")
    .Attributes["href"]
    .Value;
```